# NSString, NSArray Memory leak in method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

everytime I call this method 2 `NSString` and 1 `NSMutableArray` objects leak, which is disgusting, because i'm using it a lot in my app.

Here's the method:

```
+ (NSString *)queryStringFromParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters {
    NSMutableArray __block *entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [parameters enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *entry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", [key pcen], [obj pcen]];
        [entries addObject:entry];
    }];
    return [entries componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
}
```

Here is the `[pcen]` method

```
- (NSString *)pcen {
    CFStringRef string = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                 (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                 NULL,
                                                                 CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [(NSString *)string autorelease];
}
```

They are in the same file, my project is ARC, but for this file I unchecked ARC.
Why this leak happens every time I try to use it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not release the `entries` array.

And btw, the `__block` modifier is not necessary here, because you do not modify that variable inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

You alloc/init the NSArray in the queryStringFromParameters: method. The array you return is indeed an autoreleased object ([entries componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]) but you never release the entries array.

You can replace the line

```
NSMutableArray __block *entries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

by

```
NSMutableArray __block *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
```

to solve the issue.
The strings leak because they are saved in the leaked NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

In your queryStringFromParameters method i think there is no need to alloc entries. Simply use auto-referencing array

```
  NSMutableArray *entries = [NSMutableArray array];
```

in second method u used CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes which has second argument as u passed (CFStringRef)self but that should be OriginalString - The CFString object to copy.

An example of CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes is below:

```
CFStringRef originalURLString = CFSTR("http://online.store.com/storefront/?request=get-document&doi=10.1175%2F1520-0426(2005)014%3C1157:DODADSS%3E2.0.CO%3B2");

CFStringRef preprocessedString = CFURLCreateStringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(kCFAllocatorDefault, originalURLString, CFSTR(""), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Also remove __block as @Martin R said

Comment: I assume (although the OP did not say explicitly) that the `pcen` method is defined in a category extension on `NSString`. In that case `(CFStringRef)self` would be OK there.